# Memory Leaks in a Classic ASP application

Tags: asp-classic, windbg

I have recently inherited the maintenance of a classic ASP website, I've never done classic ASP before, so please forgive me if I'm asking daft questions.

My co-developers have already been through each and every page to make sure that sql connections are closed, collections are emptied and then set to null. However, it's a large site, clearly between us we've missed something.

I have a dump of the process when it was leaking (taken by debug diag). When I use debug diag to perform it's memory analysis it informs me that has not detected LeakTrack.dll so is unable to perform leak analysis.

I have opened up the dump using windbg and have found one heap that is much larger than the others, with 90% of the memory in one heap. However, when I try to track the blocks back to the call stacks that allocate them I always end up with:

```
invalid allocation size, possible heap corruption
```

Is there a better way to try and track when the leak is coming from? Or do you have any tips on how to create a better process dump so that I can inspect where the leaks are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

These leaks last beyond a single page? All page-local stuff should be cleaned up and deallocated once the page is finished. Without knowing more about your application, I'd suggest looking at longer-loved objects. Are you storing anything in Session or Application?

Comment: No, nothing is stored in the application, session is hardly used. Oddly, you can hit the same page 100 times, with the same parameters and get no problems, then seemingly at random, you'll get a huge spike in memory usage. Hard to replicate, harder to track down.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an ASP problem.